Langchain RAG with history and citations
I'm trying to build a RAG with langchain. I'd like to consider the chat history and to be able to produce citations. I've followed the tutorial on Langchain but I struggle to put together history and citations.
Here my code:
### Contextualize question ### This is used to forumlate the right question to the retriever
    contextualize_q_system_prompt = """Given a chat history and the latest user question \
    which might reference context in the chat history, formulate a standalone question \
    which can be understood without the chat history. Do NOT answer the question, \
    just reformulate it if needed and otherwise return it as is."""
    contextualize_q_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", contextualize_q_system_prompt),
            MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
            ("human", "{input}"),
        ]
    )
    history_aware_retriever = create_history_aware_retriever(
        llm_retriever, retriever, contextualize_q_prompt
    )
### Answer question ### This is used to answer the question based on the context
    qa_system_prompt = """You are an assistant for question-answering tasks. \
    Use the following pieces of retrieved context to answer the question. \
    If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know. \
    Use five sentences maximum and keep the answer concise.\

    Here it is the context: {context}"""
    qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", qa_system_prompt),
            MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
            ("human", "{input}"),
        ]
    )
    question_answer_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm__main, qa_prompt)

    rag_chain = create_retrieval_chain(history_aware_retriever, question_answer_chain)### Statefully manage chat history ###
    store = {}

    def get_session_history(session_id: str) -> BaseChatMessageHistory:
        if session_id not in store:
            store[session_id] = session_history #ChatMessageHistory() #hack found for now as the RunnableWithMessageHistory requires a function. To be changed when we'll handle multiple sessions
        return store[session_id]

    conversational_rag_chain = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
        rag_chain_2,
        get_session_history,
        input_messages_key="input",
        history_messages_key="chat_history",
        output_messages_key="answer",
    )

    res = conversational_rag_chain.invoke(
        {"input": query},
        config={
            "configurable": {"session_id": "abc123"}
        },  # constructs a key "abc123" in `store`.
    )

Until here everything is working well but I don't find a way to insert a change in the context so that I can use bind_tools and extract the citation as shown here https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/citations/#cite-snippets
I've tried multiple approaches but I didn't find a good solutions as I don't have enough experience with langchain.

Here is how you can see the chat_history and relevant context (may be the chunks from the vectordb, if you have ingested some docs there).
This is in addition to your code.
from langchain_core.chat_history import BaseChatMessageHistory
from langchain_core.runnables.history import RunnableWithMessageHistory
from langchain_community.chat_message_histories import ChatMessageHistory

store = {}

# Storing unique session_id to keep track of a particular conversation
def get_session_history(session_id: str) -> BaseChatMessageHistory:
    if session_id not in store:
        store[session_id] = ChatMessageHistory()
    return store[session_id]

conversational_rag_chain = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    rag_chain,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key= "input",
    history_messages_key="chat_history",
    output_messages_key="answer",
    )

# 1st Question
conversational_rag_chain.invoke(
    {"input": "Who is the president of Pakistan?"},
    config={
        "configurable": {"session_id": "abc123"}
    },  # constructs a key "abc123" in `store`.
)["answer"]

# 2nd Question
ans = conversational_rag_chain.invoke(
    {"input": "When was he elected?"},
    config={"configurable": {"session_id": "abc123"}},
)
# context/relevant docs from vectordb
print(f"{ans["answer"]} and  context: \n \n {ans["context"]}") 


I was able to achieve this using the 'Direct prompting' approach described here
Here is my version of it:
import bs4
from langchain.chains import create_history_aware_retriever, create_retrieval_chain
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain_chroma import Chroma
from langchain_community.chat_message_histories import ChatMessageHistory
from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain_core.chat_history import BaseChatMessageHistory
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_core.runnables.history import RunnableWithMessageHistory
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_text_splitters import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.7)

### Construct retriever ###
loader = WebBaseLoader(
    web_paths=("https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/",),
    bs_kwargs=dict(
        parse_only=bs4.SoupStrainer(
            class_=("post-content", "post-title", "post-header")
        )
    ),
)
docs = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
splits = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=splits, embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings())
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

### Contextualize question ###
contextualize_q_system_prompt = """Given a chat history and the latest user question \
which might reference context in the chat history, formulate a standalone question \
which can be understood without the chat history. Do NOT answer the question, \
just reformulate it if needed and otherwise return it as is."""
contextualize_q_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", contextualize_q_system_prompt),
        MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
        ("human", "{input}"),
    ]
)
history_aware_retriever = create_history_aware_retriever(
    llm, retriever, contextualize_q_prompt
)

### Answer question ###
system = """You're a helpful AI assistant. Given a user question and some Wikipedia article snippets, \
answer the user question and provide citations. If none of the articles answer the question, just say you don't know.

Remember, you must return both an answer and citations. A citation consists of a VERBATIM quote that \
justifies the answer and the ID of the quote article. Return a citation for every quote across all articles \
that justify the answer. Use the following format for your final output:

<cited_answer>
    <answer></answer>
    <citations>
        <citation><source_id></source_id><quote></quote></citation>
        <citation><source_id></source_id><quote></quote></citation>
        ...
    </citations>
</cited_answer>

Here are the Wikipedia articles:{context}"""
qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", system),
        MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
        ("human", "{input}"),
    ]
)
question_answer_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, qa_prompt)

rag_chain = create_retrieval_chain(history_aware_retriever, question_answer_chain)

### Statefully manage chat history ###
store = {}


def get_session_history(session_id: str) -> BaseChatMessageHistory:
    if session_id not in store:
        store[session_id] = ChatMessageHistory()
    return store[session_id]


conversational_rag_chain = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    rag_chain,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="input",
    history_messages_key="chat_history",
    output_messages_key="answer",
)

Here is the first question:
conversational_rag_chain.invoke(
    {"input": "What is Task Decomposition?"},
    config={
        "configurable": {"session_id": "abc123"}
    },  # constructs a key "abc123" in `store`.
)

Here is the result:
{'input': 'What is Task Decomposition?',
 'chat_history': [],
 'context': [Document(page_content='Fig. 1. Overview of a LLM-powered autonomous agent system.\nComponent One: Planning#\nA complicated task usually involves many steps. An agent needs to know what they are and plan ahead.\nTask Decomposition#\nChain of thought (CoT; Wei et al. 2022) has become a standard prompting technique for enhancing model performance on complex tasks. The model is instructed to “think step by step” to utilize more test-time computation to decompose hard tasks into smaller and simpler steps. CoT transforms big tasks into multiple manageable tasks and shed lights into an interpretation of the model’s thinking process.', metadata={'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/'}),
  Document(page_content='Fig. 1. Overview of a LLM-powered autonomous agent system.\nComponent One: Planning#\nA complicated task usually involves many steps. An agent needs to know what they are and plan ahead.\nTask Decomposition#\nChain of thought (CoT; Wei et al. 2022) has become a standard prompting technique for enhancing model performance on complex tasks. The model is instructed to “think step by step” to utilize more test-time computation to decompose hard tasks into smaller and simpler steps. CoT transforms big tasks into multiple manageable tasks and shed lights into an interpretation of the model’s thinking process.', metadata={'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/'}),
  Document(page_content='Fig. 1. Overview of a LLM-powered autonomous agent system.\nComponent One: Planning#\nA complicated task usually involves many steps. An agent needs to know what they are and plan ahead.\nTask Decomposition#\nChain of thought (CoT; Wei et al. 2022) has become a standard prompting technique for enhancing model performance on complex tasks. The model is instructed to “think step by step” to utilize more test-time computation to decompose hard tasks into smaller and simpler steps. CoT transforms big tasks into multiple manageable tasks and shed lights into an interpretation of the model’s thinking process.', metadata={'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/'}),
  Document(page_content='Fig. 1. Overview of a LLM-powered autonomous agent system.\nComponent One: Planning#\nA complicated task usually involves many steps. An agent needs to know what they are and plan ahead.\nTask Decomposition#\nChain of thought (CoT; Wei et al. 2022) has become a standard prompting technique for enhancing model performance on complex tasks. The model is instructed to “think step by step” to utilize more test-time computation to decompose hard tasks into smaller and simpler steps. CoT transforms big tasks into multiple manageable tasks and shed lights into an interpretation of the model’s thinking process.', metadata={'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/'})],
 'answer': '<cited_answer>\n    <answer>Task Decomposition involves transforming big tasks into multiple manageable tasks.</answer>\n    <citations>\n        <citation><source_id>Component One: Planning</source_id><quote>Task Decomposition# Chain of thought (CoT; Wei et al. 2022) has become a standard prompting technique for enhancing model performance on complex tasks. The model is instructed to “think step by step” to utilize more test-time computation to decompose hard tasks into smaller and simpler steps. CoT transforms big tasks into multiple manageable tasks and shed lights into an interpretation of the model’s thinking process.</quote></citation>\n    </citations>\n</cited_answer>'}

Here is the second question:
conversational_rag_chain.invoke(
    {"input": "What are common ways of doing it?"},
    config={"configurable": {"session_id": "abc123"}},
)

Here is the result:
{'input': 'What are common ways of doing it?',
 'chat_history': [HumanMessage(content='What is Task Decomposition?'),
  AIMessage(content='<cited_answer>\n    <answer>Task decomposition involves breaking down complex tasks into smaller and simpler steps to make them more manageable.</answer>\n    <citations>\n        <citation><source_id>0</source_id>Chain of thought (CoT; Wei et al. 2022) has become a standard prompting technique for enhancing model performance on complex tasks. The model is instructed to “think step by step” to utilize more test-time computation to decompose hard tasks into smaller and simpler steps.</citation>\n        <citation><source_id>1</source_id>Tree of Thoughts (Yao et al. 2023) extends CoT by exploring multiple reasoning possibilities at each step. It first decomposes the problem into multiple thought steps and generates multiple thoughts per step, creating a tree structure.</citation>\n        <citation><source_id>1</source_id>Task decomposition can be done (1) by LLM with simple prompting like "Steps for XYZ.\\n1.", "What are the subgoals for achieving XYZ?", (2) by using task-specific instructions; e.g. "Write a story outline." for writing a novel, or (3) with human inputs.</citation>\n    </citations>\n</cited_answer>')],
 'context': [Document(page_content='Tree of Thoughts (Yao et al. 2023) extends CoT by exploring multiple reasoning possibilities at each step. It first decomposes the problem into multiple thought steps and generates multiple thoughts per step, creating a tree structure. The search process can be BFS (breadth-first search) or DFS (depth-first search) with each state evaluated by a classifier (via a prompt) or majority vote.\nTask decomposition can be done (1) by LLM with simple prompting like "Steps for XYZ.\\n1.", "What are the subgoals for achieving XYZ?", (2) by using task-specific instructions; e.g. "Write a story outline." for writing a novel, or (3) with human inputs.', metadata={'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/'}),
  Document(page_content='Tree of Thoughts (Yao et al. 2023) extends CoT by exploring multiple reasoning possibilities at each step. It first decomposes the problem into multiple thought steps and generates multiple thoughts per step, creating a tree structure. The search process can be BFS (breadth-first search) or DFS (depth-first search) with each state evaluated by a classifier (via a prompt) or majority vote.\nTask decomposition can be done (1) by LLM with simple prompting like "Steps for XYZ.\\n1.", "What are the subgoals for achieving XYZ?", (2) by using task-specific instructions; e.g. "Write a story outline." for writing a novel, or (3) with human inputs.', metadata={'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/'}),
  Document(page_content='Fig. 1. Overview of a LLM-powered autonomous agent system.\nComponent One: Planning#\nA complicated task usually involves many steps. An agent needs to know what they are and plan ahead.\nTask Decomposition#\nChain of thought (CoT; Wei et al. 2022) has become a standard prompting technique for enhancing model performance on complex tasks. The model is instructed to “think step by step” to utilize more test-time computation to decompose hard tasks into smaller and simpler steps. CoT transforms big tasks into multiple manageable tasks and shed lights into an interpretation of the model’s thinking process.', metadata={'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/'}),
  Document(page_content='Fig. 1. Overview of a LLM-powered autonomous agent system.\nComponent One: Planning#\nA complicated task usually involves many steps. An agent needs to know what they are and plan ahead.\nTask Decomposition#\nChain of thought (CoT; Wei et al. 2022) has become a standard prompting technique for enhancing model performance on complex tasks. The model is instructed to “think step by step” to utilize more test-time computation to decompose hard tasks into smaller and simpler steps. CoT transforms big tasks into multiple manageable tasks and shed lights into an interpretation of the model’s thinking process.', metadata={'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/'})],
 'answer': '<cited_answer>\n    <answer>Common ways of task decomposition include using simple prompting, task-specific instructions, and human inputs.</answer>\n    <citations>\n        <citation><source_id>1</source_id>Task decomposition can be done (1) by LLM with simple prompting like "Steps for XYZ.\\n1.", "What are the subgoals for achieving XYZ?", (2) by using task-specific instructions; e.g. "Write a story outline." for writing a novel, or (3) with human inputs.</citation>\n    </citations>\n</cited_answer>'}

Here’s a summary of the changes I made to the original code:

Modified the System Prompt in the ‘Answer question’ section: I replaced the original system prompt in the ‘Answer question’ section with a new one that instructs the AI to answer the user’s question using Wikipedia article snippets and provide citations. The new system prompt also specifies the format of the output.
Modified the Question-Answering Chain: I updated the question_answer_chain to use the new system prompt. This chain is responsible for answering the user’s question based on the retrieved context and the chat history.
Updated the Retrieval-Generation Chain: I updated the rag_chain to use the new history_aware_retriever and question_answer_chain. This    chain is responsible for retrieving relevant context based on the    user’s question and the chat history, and then generating an answer based on the retrieved context.
Kept the Chat History Management section intact: I didn’t make any changes to the section of your code that manages the chat history.

These changes integrate the new functionality into conversational_rag_chain while keeping its original functionality intact. The conversational_rag_chain will now answer questions based on a chat history and retrieved context, and also use Wikipedia article snippets to provide citations when answering questions.
Hope this helps!
